# Join on stored variables in a loop

Tags: r, loops, join

I need to anti join on variables that are implicitly stored and updated in a loop. Here is the code:

```
    #initialize vectors
SourceColumn = NULL
TargetColumn = NULL
InSource_NotInTarget = NULL
InTarget_NotInSource = NULL
CountNASource = NULL
CountNATarget = NULL
Count_Source_Total_Rows = NULL
Count_Target_Total_Rows = NULL
Count_Source_Unique_Rows = NULL
Count_Target_Unique_Rows = NULL
SourceRowType = NULL
TargetRowType = NULL

for (i in names(nmMappingLOAD_CC_C_PROJECT_CONFIG)){
  a1Ind = paste(i)
  a2Ind = paste(nmMappingLOAD_CC_C_PROJECT_CONFIG[i])


  #DB data(Target)
  a1 = adhocTibl[a1Ind]
  #Excel data(Source)
  a2 = excelData[a2Ind]

  #Build col vectors

  #fails here
  Count_InTarget_NotInSource = append(InTarget_NotInSource, nrow(anti_join(a1, a2, by = c(names(a1) = names(a2)))))
  Count_InSource_NotInTarget = append(InSource_NotInTarget, nrow(anti_join(a2, a1, by = c("PROJECT_ID"="PROJECT_CONFIG_ID"))))


}
```

It fails here `Count_InTarget_NotInSource = append(InTarget_NotInSource, nrow(anti_join(a1, a2, by = c(names(a1) = names(a2)))))`

With the error `Error: Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`

I can explicitly state the join columns like `by = c("PROJECT_CONFIG_ID"="PROJECT_ID"))))` and it will work, but for this case, I am looping through multiple columns in both tables and the column names are updated in the loop.

Comment: Any alternative solutions are also welcome. I am surprised such a basic feature is so difficult to do in R.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by using setnames:

```
  Count_InTarget_NotInSource = append(InTarget_NotInSource, nrow(anti_join(a1, a2, by = setNames(names(a2), names(a1)))))
```